# Search based on multiple checkbox selection and provide union as result

Tags: sql

I have 3 checkboxes.

- When `Checkbox1` is selected then fetch all records with A = 1.
- When `Checkbox2` is selected then fetch all records with B = 1.
- When `Checkbox3` is selected then fetch all records with A = 0 and B=0.
- When multiple checkboxes are selected then I need the union of results.
- When none of the checkboxes is selected then, all records should be fetched.

For example: if both `Checkbox1` and `Checkbox3` are selected, then fetch all records with A=1 plus those records which have both A=0 and B=0.

I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT FROM CarData
WHERE (@IsCheckbox1=0 OR (@IsCheckbox1=1 AND A=1))
AND   (@IsCheckbox2=0 OR (@IsCheckbox2=1 AND B=1))                      
AND   (@IsCheckbox3=0 OR (@IsCheckbox3=1 AND A=0 AND B=0))
```

But, its not working correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "union" of all results suggests that you want `OR` between the conditions.  So the conditions look like this:

```
SELECT FROM CarData
WHERE ( (@IsCheckbox1 = 1 AND A = 1) OR
        (@IsCheckbox2 = 1 AND B = 1) OR
        (@IsCheckbox3 = 1 AND A = 0 AND B = 0)
      )
```

Comment: What if all checkboxes are `0` ?

Comment: @sagi . . . I think that is a question for the OP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : If all checkboxes are 0, then all records should be fetched.

Comment: Not really, you can see in his query that all records will be selected in that situation ..

Comment: @sagi . . . The question was edited after I answered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Right! I edited the question and then commented for the condition of all checkboxes = 0. Please update answer accordingly, so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CarData WHERE A = CASE WHEN @IsCheckbox1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END OR B = CASE WHEN @IsCheckbox2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UNION for each condition

```
SELECT * FROM CarData WHERE (@IsCheckbox1=0 OR (@IsCheckbox1=1 AND A=1))
UNION
SELECT * FROM CarData WHERE (@IsCheckbox2=0 OR (@IsCheckbox2=1 AND B=1))
UNION                    
SELECT * FROM CarData WHERE (@IsCheckbox3=0 OR (@IsCheckbox3=1 AND A=0 AND B=0))
```

Comment: I do not think you need @IsCheckbox1=0 OR,@IsCheckbox2=0 OR,@IsCheckbox3=0 OR.